# Qt draw a blue pixel if the original pixel was black in a new image

Tags: c++, qt

I've written some code that should make a new image. My background image has black areas, when the for loop comes on a black pixel then it should draw in the new image a blue one instead otherwise it should just draw the original pixel. Thought I could do that like this but the program keeps running.

```
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
int c, m, y, k, al;
QColor color;
QColor drawColor;
QImage background;
QImage world(1500, 768, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QSize sizeImage;
int height, width;
background.load("Background.jpg");
world.fill(1);
QPainter painter(&background);
sizeImage = background.size();
width = sizeImage.width();
height = sizeImage.height();

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int z = 0; z < width; z++)
    {
        color = QColor::fromRgb (background.pixel(i,z) );
        color.getCmyk(&c,&m,&y,&k,&al);

        if(c == 0 && m == 0 && y == 0 && k == 0) //then we have black as color and then we draw the color blue
        {
            drawColor.setBlue(255);
            painter.setPen(drawColor);
            painter.drawPoint(i,z);
        }
    }

}


//adding new image to the graphicsScene
QGraphicsPixmapItem item( QPixmap::fromImage(background));
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
scene->addItem(&item);

QGraphicsView view(scene);
view.show();
```

Is my for loop wrong or is it my painter? It sais QImage::pixel: coordinate (292,981) out of range but for soo many pixels, it is also not fast enough to use.

Comment: What do you mean by "the program keeps running"? It never comes out of the for loop? You don't get the result you expect?

Comment: Is it simply that the loop is incredibly slow?  It seems to me that transforming a large image by reading and writing individual pixels like that is going to lag a little!

Comment: What's a better approach then? I thought maybe only redraw the blue pixels but I don't know how to loop over the image.

Comment: Tell us what the problem is. Does it never finish? Does it finish, but is it slow? Is the result you get wrong? ....

Comment: I've edited the code now it shows pretty fast, but the black is still black and not blue. Check the edited code.

Comment: How black is that .jpg? JPEG compression optimizes image sizes for human consumption. Since humans can't distinguish black and dark grey very well, compression may change black to grey. It will certainly do so for thin black lines (<8 px) on a white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, drawing pixels one by one can be incredibly slow. Even pixel-by-pixel access can be [quite slow](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel). E.g. the following is probably faster, but still not very good:

```
  const QRgb black = 0;
  const QRgb blue = 255;
  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      if (background.pixel(x,y) == black) {
         background.SetPixel(blue);
      }
    }
  }
```

The quicker solution involves direct bitoperations via `scanline()`. You might want to call `convertToFormat()` first, so you don't need to deal with the different possible scanline formats.

As a creative hack, call `createMaskFromColor` to make all black pixels transparent, and then paint over a blue background.

Comment: Thanks this is very fast, but the code doesn't change anything to blue.

Comment: Well, I left out the actual painting part. This just changes `QImage background`. You still need a `painter.drawImage()` call. (Oh, and it's very picky about black. Dark dark grey is not black).

Comment: A oké, so after the whole while loop I just need to draw the image again or do you mean in the if test?

Comment: @user1007522: After the for-loops; that's how you gain speed. You'll access the videocard memory only once, for a single large data transfer. They're good at that.

Comment: K I get it, but still if I painter.drawImage(0,0,background); and the painter is defined on the world image, then still world is like the original image. And Black is hex 00000 in my image drawned with ilustrator.

Comment: Save as .PNG instead, that is pixel-perfect.

Comment: Done that it is .png now png-24 (illustrator) this is my code now http://pastebin.com/CGKxuasG and still not blue, are the x and y not switched in the if test?

Comment: Note sure what you mean by "switched". `x` should certainly be the inner loop.